# Does Codepush collects data?

Tags: android, google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I have added codepush for CI/CD in my react native project but my app is getting rejected on google play console stating this :

> We found an issue in the following area(s):
> SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID, MAC address)

The only package that I think is causing this is the codepush from appcenter.
Can anyone confirm this ?

Comment: Did you find anything out?

Comment: Yes, it was related to data safety declaration. nothing more than that